# Is it possible to send a String[] through Multipart using Retrofit?

Tags: android, multipartform-data, retrofit2

I'm developing an application where at a point the user has to choose any number of countries from a list and I must send the selected names through a multipart.

I am not uploading any file along with the String[], but there is no route to upload information without it being a multipart and I don't have any saying in how the web server operates.

I've attempted to simply send it as an Array, ArrayList and JsonArray as such:

```
@Headers({
    "Connection: Keep-Alive",
})
@Multipart
@PUT("/user/{id}")
String updateUser(@Path("id") int userId, @Part("user[countries]") String[] countries);
```

I've also attempted [this solution](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/811), but I either misunderstood it or it does not work. Here is the code I attempted to use:

```
ArrayList<String> countries = CountryManager.getInstance().getSelectedCountryIds();
RequestBody requestBody;
LinkedHashMap<String, RequestBody> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(int i = 0; i < countries.size(); i++) {
    requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), countries.get(i));
    hashMap.put("countries["+i+"]", requestBody);
}
```

And changing the retrofit method accordingly:

```
@Headers({
    "Connection: Keep-Alive",
})
@Multipart
@PUT("/user/{id}")
String updateUser(@Path("id") int userId, @PartMap() Map countries);
```

However in all attempts I've gotten the error retrofit.RetrofitError: Part body must not be null.

I've also mentioned that the ChangeLog for retrofit mentions "New: Support iterable and array `@Part` parameters using OkHttp's `MultipartBody.Part`", but after some digging, I've found the given example quite confusing to the point that I'm unsure on how to implement it in my code and was unable to find a tutorial that even mentioned sending arrays in a multipart.

Is such a thing simply impossible?

Comment: The solution using PartMap annotation seems to be right. I used it in some apps and works fine. Are you sure that all the countries are not null?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know I am late for this answer. you can use `@Query("someKey[]")` for sending arraylist in multipart. Heres is the working example.

```
@Multipart
    @POST("./")
    Call<JsonElement> addSubEvent(@Part(EndAPI.USE_CASE) RequestBody useCase,
                                  @Query("event_id[]") ArrayList<String> event_id,
                                  @Query("user_id[]") ArrayList<String> user_id,
                                  @Query("name[]") ArrayList<String> name,
                                  @Query("date_time[]") ArrayList<String> date_time,
                                  @Part("token") RequestBody token,
                                  @Part MultipartBody.Part... profilePic);
```

Hope It will help some one seeking for the answer.

Comment: how to parse the arraylist in php

Answer (score 10):

creating multi part list to use as a array list

```
List<MultipartBody.Part> descriptionList = new ArrayList<>();
descriptionList.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("param_name_here", values));
```

following is the function in service interface of retrofit.

```
@PUT("/")
@Multipart
Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhotos(
        @Part MultipartBody.Part placeId,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part name,
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> desclist, // <-- use such for list of same parameter
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files  // <-- multiple photos here
);
```

Hope it helps someone. cheers... !!!

Comment: Its worked for passing list of String through Multipart.. Thanks @Siddher

Comment: Saved much of my time, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Just use @Part("items[]") List items

Like this:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList();
    items.add("1");
    items.add("2");
    items.add("3");

@Multipart
@POST("/")
Call<Result> yourMethod(@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap, @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> map, @Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("items[]") List<String> items);
```

Comment: how to parse this array in php??

Answer (score -1):

this is possible and that too using multiparts, just convert your Array into Json String and add it as a single part and once this Json is received at Server side, just deserialize it.