# how to send List<String> with retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm sending a multipart request to server and this is my interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("v1/group/new")
Call<MyResponse> newGroup(
        @Header("token") String token,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part photo,
        @Part("title") RequestBody subject,
        @Part("members") List<RequestBody> members);
```

and for sending my members in my fragment, I change my `List<String>` to `List<RequestBody>` as below:

```
List<RequestBody> members = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0;i < membersId.size(); i++){
    members.add(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),membersId.get(i)));
}
```

and it's working with multiple members! but when there is a one string in my list, retrofit doesn't sends my members as a list!!! for example:

I want to send array of strings like this :

["item1","item2","item3"]

my code works for this, but when there is only one item, retrofit sends this :

"item1"

instead of ["item1"]

what is the proper way of sending array of string in multipart with retrofit?

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223092/is-it-possible-to-send-a-string-through-multipart-using-retrofit)

Comment: @MD I've seen this link before, but non of it answers help me, thank you!

Comment: Did you try to add `@Part("members[]") List<RequestBody> members);` note `[ ]` at the end of "members"

Comment: @ArbenMaloku I totally missed `[ ]` . and it's fixed now. please answer my question so I can accept it. thank you very much for your help

Comment: Is this solution working for you ? It is not working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like this.

```
@Multipart
@POST("v1/group/new")
Call<MyResponse> newGroup(
        @Header("token") String token,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part photo,
        @Part("title") RequestBody subject,
        @Part("members[]") List<RequestBody> members);
```

Remember you must add `[]` to your members param :).

Comment: `"members[]"` is not working with `FormUrlEncoded` , and `[]` remains in the key! and the problem with one item will not be solved. do you have any solution for sending array with `FormUrlEncoded`? according to this:
 https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded 
there is no need for `[]` , but in one item, it sends without `[]`!

Comment: Try this `@Field("members[]")`. And let me know if it works.

Comment: I've tried it and its not working! in the server, the `[]` remains in the key!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Multipart
@POST("v1/group/new")
Call<MyResponse> newGroup(
        @Header("token") String token,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part photo,
        @Part("title") RequestBody subject,
        @Part("members[]") ArrayList<RequestBody> members);
```

Two changes:

1. Change list to ArrayList as ArrayList is Serializable whereas List is not.
2. add "[]" at the end of the ArrayList type parameter.