# How to send ArrayList and Multipart through retrofit2? (Error: expected begin_object but was string)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, multipartform-data

I am new to retrofit and made a multipart body to upload file. Here is the code:

#ApiConfig.java

```
public interface ApiConfig {
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload.php")
    Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(@Part("details[]") ArrayList<String> details, @Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("file")RequestBody name);
}
```

#AppConfig.java

```
public class AppConfig {
    private static String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.1:8080/xampp/app/";
    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
}
```

#ServerResponse.java

```
public class ServerResponse {
    @SerializedName("success")
    boolean success;
    @SerializedName("message")
    String message;
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }
}
```

#MainActivity.java

```
    private void uploadFile(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
        RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());

        ArrayList<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add("name");
        details.add("id");
        ApiConfig getResponse = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(ApiConfig.class);
        Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.uploadFile(details, fileToUpload, filename);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                ServerResponse serverResponse = (ServerResponse) response.body();
                if (serverResponse != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, serverResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was an error while uploading your file. Please try again later.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was an error while uploading your file. Please try again later.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Everything works fine by replacing this part in the ApiConfig.java:

```
Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(@Part("details[]") ArrayList<String> details, @Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("file")RequestBody name);
```

with just

```
Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("file")RequestBody name);
```

The error that I am receiving is

```
expected begin_object but was string
```

Retrofit just doesn't allow me to send array with the file. Please let me know how to fix this error and receive the array in a PHP file. Regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to send a String\[\] through Multipart using Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223092/is-it-possible-to-send-a-string-through-multipart-using-retrofit)

Comment: Sorry but no. It was from this question that I edited my code to accept arraylist but the error persists.